# Left column of vertical table with arrows does not resize

Tags: css

I convertet an horizontal breadcrumb-menu with arrow-look into an vertical timeline using `:before` and `:after` elements to generate the arrows.
The Left columns is marked as `th` and has to defined as `display: block` so that the arrows can be generated.
My problem is, that the definition as `display: block` avoids the `table-cell` to adjust its height according to the `table-cell` right of it.

For better understanding, you can have al look at [this link](http://vorschau.e-friedrich.de/ueber-uns/geschichte/)

The site is responsive, so that i cant't define fixed height-values.
The error occurs if you resize the window to less than 400px.

Maybe someone has an idea for me... ?  :)

Here ist the code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" class="zeitstrahl">
      <tr>
        <th class="datum1" scope="row">1947</th>
        <td>Unternehmensgründung durch Erich Friedrich </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum2" scope="row">1951</th>
        <td>Bau der ersten  Aufbereitungsanlage in Stiddien bei Braunschweig,<br>
        Jahresleistung 100.000 t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum3" scope="row">1954</th>
        <td><p>Bau einer Anlage in Salzgitter  Drütte mit einer Jahresleistung <br>
        von 600.000 t</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum4" scope="row">1964</th>
        <td>Standortwechsel nach  Salzgitter-Immendorf und Bau einer Anlage in Salzgitter Immendorf auf dem Gelände des  heutigen Reststoffzentrum 
        Barum (RZB)  mit einer Anfangskapazität von 600.000 t/a und der Erweiterung auf eine  Jahresleistung von 1.200.000 t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum5" scope="row">1980</th>
        <td>Weltweiter Bau von  Aufbereitungsanlagen    Mit  einem Partner wurden Anlagen u.a. in Indien, China, Ungarn, der UdSSR mit  Jahreskapazitäten von 1,0 bis 3,5 Million t geplant und errichtet.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum6" scope="row">1990</th>
        <td>Bündelung der  Aufbereitungsaktivitäten in einer separaten Gesellschaft und Gründung der Firmen ERICH FRIEDRICH Hüttenservice  GmbH 
        und ERICH FRIEDRICH Handel GmbH</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum7" scope="row">2000</th>
        <td>Beginn einer weiteren  Expansionsphase<br>
          ERICH FRIEDRICH Handel GmbH führt  Entsorgungsdienstleistungen 
            in den Stahlwerken der Salzgitter Flachstahl  GmbH und der 
            Georgsmarienhütte GmbH durch, u.a. den  Transport von flüssiger 
            Schlacke, Betreiben der Schlackebette und  die anschließende 
        Aufbereitung zu wiederverwertbaren Hüttenreststoffen</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="datum8" scope="row">heute</th>
        <td>Aufbereitungsaktivitäten für die <a href="http://www.peiner-traeger.de" title="Peiner Träger GmbH" target="_blank">Peiner Träger GmbH</a></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

***CSS:***

```
table.zeitstrahl { margin-top: 0px; }

.zeitstrahl th {
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    width: 120px;       
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background: #004993;                   /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(210,100%,15%,1);           
}

.zeitstrahl th:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid hsla(210,100%,15%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;          
    margin-left: -60px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.zeitstrahl th:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.zeitstrahl td { padding: 20px; vertical-align: middle; display:table-cell; }

.zeitstrahl .datum1 { padding-top: 20px; }

.zeitstrahl .datum2 { background: hsla(210,100%,25%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum2:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,25%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum3 { background: hsla(210,100%,35%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum3:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,35%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum4 { background: hsla(210,100%,45%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum4:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,45%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum5 { background: hsla(210,100%,55%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum5:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,55%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum6 { background: hsla(210,100%,65%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum6:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,65%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum7 { background: hsla(210,100%,75%,1); }
.zeitstrahl .datum7:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,75%,1); }

.zeitstrahl .datum8 { background: hsla(210,100%,75%,1); margin-top: -30px; }
.zeitstrahl .datum8:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,75%,1); }

.zeitstrahl th:hover { background: hsla(210,100%,25%,1); }
.zeitstrahl th:hover:after { border-top-color: hsla(210,100%,25%,1) !important; }
```

Comment: I am getting some buggy response in FF 17.0.1 for the last 2 links. When I hover over the last 2 arrows a blue bar comes up showing the rectangular nature of the links. May want to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<th>` needs `display: block` to make `position: relative` valid in Firefox. But because of this its height won't fill the table-row because it isn't behaving as a table-cell anymore.
To fix this you have to remove `display: block` from `<th>`. But because we need `position: relative` for the arrows to work, I set `display: block; position: relative;` to its parent: the table-row. Then I had to play with `th:after, th:before` bottom and left values because the percentages don't work anymore. I don't know if `tr { display: block; }`, will cause any other problem in the future, but it does the job.
After doing this, the `<th>` will behave as a normal table-cell, which makes it shrink when the window is too small. To fix that I set `th { min-width: 120px }`.
So here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/BpFwe). The changes are marked with comments. Works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but not in IE8-. Haven't tested IE8+.

Comment: Hi Angel Yan,

thanks a lot for your help And a lot for the very good explanation, too.
All works fine. IE9, has now a problem with the arrows. I made a css-workaround to hide them and now it looks like in IE8 and lower without the arrows – still good enough for that audience ;)

Comment: You are welcome. IE has always been tricky to deal with. At least you are not reducing the functionality of the page.